# Help recognize / how to remove and reinstall this window

Tags: repair, windows

We have a double hung window with a dual-track piece on both sides. The lower sash can no longer stay open as its spring coil on the right has fallen detached.

I've watched quite a few YouTube videos on window removal and have a basic idea. However, I didn't find one with the precise mechanism for my window so I wanted to pick the brains of the experts out here. Is the small wood piece the window stop that I have to remove before I can slide out the track?

**EDIT:** It looks like that the window was the original one installed in 1990, [Eagle Flat Clad](http://element.eaglewindow.com/support_dhhistory.asp). I can't seem to find replacement parts for it. Is it possible to keep the window by getting a new jamb liner?

[image: double hung window]
[image: window track]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just above the sash, in the 2nd pic, can you push that track in (towards the window frame)? If so, follow along, if not skip down to "Continue Here".

If so, you simply push both tracks in and pull the top of the sash out. This will allow you to tip the window horizontally into the room. Use this feature to wash the outside glass.

There will be some sort of mechanism holding the bottom of the sash into the track. Usually this is disengaged by lifting one side of the sash, allowing it to slide up, while holding the other side of the sash in place. This will disengage these lower clips allowing you to completely remove the sash from the opening. **Take a look *now* to ensure you understand how the mechanism latches into place.** Maybe even take a couple of pics so you don't forget. Are there moving pieces?  If so, how are they arranged immediately upon removal?  They'll likely move at some point during your work and you'll need to know how to put them back so you can reattach the sash later. Trust me on this - you'll save yourself frustration later. Don't ask how I know these things... :/

In order to completely remove the track, you'll want to first remove both sashes (top and bottom). Since these look like replacement windows in the original opening, it's possible that the tracks are simply screwed in place and once you've got the sashes out of the way you'll be able to unscrew them. If they don't unscrew then...

#### Continue Here

You'll need to remove the stop. That is the piece of wood you see on the inside of the house right next to the track.

Using a sharp (new) utility knife, carefully slice the paint between the stop and the window trim (to prevent the removal process from pulling up extra paint). Then gently work a stiff putty knife or other thin pry bar into that slight gap. If you have to pry, I'd suggest a scrap piece of wood under whatever you're prying with to prevent the metal from digging into the wood and leaving a gouge that you'll later have to patch up.

Once you've got the stops out of the way, you should be able to figure out how to remove the tracks.

I'm not sure if you'll be able to reattach the springs (the one in the pic looks like it's attached and stretched slightly, maybe it's the one on the other side that isn't). If the spring is broken, you'd have to replace it.

If a replacement is necessary... I'm not sure. You don't seem to know who manufactured the windows - maybe there is identifying info on the back of the track. Contact them to see if there's a warranty (our windows, replaced last summer come with a warranty that's transferable to the next owner), or if you can buy replacements parts or whole tracks. You'll probably need to supply them with the dimensions of the sash, as the springs are balanced against the weight of the window.

If there are no manufacturer marks on the tracks (unlikely, I'd think), you'll probably have to contact a window company to see if they can help you out. You may be able to get a "generic" replacement, or you might find someone with the knowledge to identify the manufacturer based on the track and attachment mechanism design.

In any case, it may take anywhere from a day to a few weeks to get replacement parts, so be prepared to replace the sashes while you're waiting. Reassemble in the opposite order of disassembly. If you have to pry the stop off, nail it back in, but leave the nails proud so it's easy to pull them when your replacement parts come in. You don't want to have to go through all that work of prying it off a second time!

Comment: Very clever observation! I was able to push the track in and pull the top of the sash out. After rotating the sash 90 degrees to horizontal position, the key way opens up and the sash can be lifted out of the track. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any label with the make & model of this dual track system. I was able to reattach the spring coil back through the loop. However, with the reattached spring, the sash still won't stay in place although it now hangs with a narrow opening at the bottom. I added a separate answer with pictures to document the mechanism in case any one finds it useful.

Comment: Also, the pictures I took were indeed of a working window sash (another astute observation!). There were no screws inside the tracks. I wonder if they could have been glued in place. If I am to replace them, I think I would try prying them out first before removing the window stops.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the great pointers from [@FreeMan](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/193330/104944). I was able to remove the window sashes from the tracks. Replacing the tracks themselves likely requires the window stops to be removed. I am documenting the mechanisms here in case other people finds this question from Google.

First, I pushed the track in and was then able to squeeze the top of the sash out of the track. I did this one side at a time. After that I rotated the sash 90 degrees inward to horizontal position, the key way opened up and the sash could be lifted out of the track. I was able to reattach the spring coil back through the loop. The mechanism in the track is locked in place when the keyway points up and is mobile if I rotates it to point horizontally using a flat screwdriver. I adjusted the height of this mechanism in order to reattach the spring more easily. However, even with the spring coil reattached, the sash still won't stay in place although it now hangs with a narrow opening at the bottom.

If anyone recognizes the make & model of this window/track system, please comment. I very much hope I can order a replacement part.

**EDIT:** It looks like that the window was the original one installed in 1990, [Eagle Flat Clad](http://element.eaglewindow.com/support_dhhistory.asp). I can't seem to find replacement parts for it. Is it possible to keep the window by getting a new jamb liner?

[image: key on sash]
[image: sliding mechanism inside track]

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you out. From the looks of that spring & latch mechanism in the 2nd pic here, I'd venture to say these are older windows - they tend to use a lot more plastic these days. Also, your spring is shot - the gaps you see between the coils indicate that the spring has stretched and just won't recoil to its originally designed shape. If there's no name visible on the inside of the track, it may be printed/stamped on the back side. Best of luck getting them replaced - I don't know what the aftermarket is like for these...

Comment: You may want to unscrew that attachment point from the bottom of the sash - there may be a mfg stamp on the back side of it, too. If you can't find any markings, I'd suggest calling a couple of local window installation companies to ask if they can/will help you with replacement springs. Based on pics or in-person inspection, and weighing each sash, they may be able to create a spring for you that will both attach into the existing mechanism and be the right strength for the sash. You may have to pay for this, but it'll be cheaper than replacing the whole window.

Comment: Thanks for the additional pointers! I'll call a few places (and ask really nicely) to see if anyone is willing to help.

Comment: Looks like it's the original window installed in 1990, [Eagle Flat Clad](http://element.eaglewindow.com/support_dhhistory.asp) and I can't seem to find replacement parts for it. Is it possible to keep the window by getting a new jamb liner?

Comment: Great detective work! Sine Eagle is now owned by Anderson Windows (according to the link you provided), I'd suggest contacting an Anderson Windows installer in your area to see what help they can provide. A good sales rep will do everything he can to find you an inexpensive way of fixing this, a not so good one will immediately tell you the only option is to replace the whole unit. If you find the 2nd one on your first call, call another installer. Of course, it's possible that they don't have any parts for it anymore...

Comment: ...but since they're still advertising it, they might. An option might be to replace the track _and_ the attachment point on the sash with a newer fitting, since it just screws in. Something to ask about. Further questions on this will likely be above my pay grade, and SE will probably warn us about "conversations in chat" (a Bad Thing™) soon, so I'll sign off here. If you have more questions, feel free to ask a whole new question (referencing this one, if you'd like). Good luck!